# How many different devices has Doom been ported to?

Tags: doom

Classic Doom is somewhat famous for running on assorted devices that aren't intended to play games, such as printers and smart fridges.

How many different devices has the game been demonstrated to run on? To clarify, I am not asking for every device model—I'm not interested in knowing about *which* printers it's been run on; just the fact that it *has* been played on a printer is enough.

Comment: Why don't printers or fridges count? Why don't they count as devices?

Comment: @Frank, I read it as running on a fridge or printer counts, but not to list all the specific models of printers (e.g. Epson Workforce 630)

Answer (score 9):

There is a wide range of devices which have had Doom specifically ported.

An issue with definitively saying what it has been ported to is that it has been ported to several programming languages which can run across many devices. It has been ported to the Android Operating System, which opens up many "smart" devices. The port to HTML5 allows it to be run on any device with access to a reasonable web browser. The port to Java opens up even more devices (more on this at the end).

From wikipedia [Official Versions of Doom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Official_versions_of_Doom), and 
expanding with [List of Doom Source Ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Doom_source_ports).

- Personal computers

  - MS-DOS
  - NEXTSTEP
  - OS/2
  - IRIX
  - Solaris
  - Mac OS
  - Linux
  - Microsoft Windows
  - Acorn RISC OS
- Consoles

  - Atari Jaguar
  - Sega 32X
  - Super NES
  - PlayStation
  - 3DO Interactive Multiplayer
  - Sega Saturn
  - Xbox
  - Xbox 360
  - PlayStation 3
- Portable devices

  - Tapwave Zodiac
  - iPhone and iPod Touch
  - Game Boy Advance
  - Nintendo DS
  - Digita OS
  - Android
  - Sony Ericsson
  - Symbian
  - Zune and Zune HD
  - TI-Nspire Series
- Language Ports

  - HTML5
  - Adobe Flash
  - Java
  - Python
  - Hewlett-Packard 16700 series Logic Analyzers
- Arbitrary Devices

  - [ATM machine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PW5ELKTivbE)
  - [Car](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NRMpNA86e8Q)
  - [DVD Player](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e0hiCKWTEss)
  - [Oscilliscope](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xZaKlLyikKg) (windows or linux)
  - [Smart Watch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2XLpbwpxeko) (android)
  - [TI-83 Plus Graphing Calculator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nduMTX86Zl0)
  - [Macbook Touchbar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GD0L46y3IqI)

As mentioned earlier, a Java Port is particularly problematic for a comprehensive list.

From the old [Learn About Java Technology](https://web.archive.org/web/20121227100452/http://java.com/en/about) page

> 100% of all Blu-ray players run Java
>   Java powers set-top boxes, printers, Web cams, games, car navigation systems, lottery terminals, medical devices, parking payment stations, and more.

Comment: You forgot a [TI-83 Plus Graphing Calculator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nduMTX86Zl0).

Comment: The Wikipedia article is incomplete, at the very least; Doom runs on a car.

Comment: It could take you a while. You'll have to throw the MacBook pro Touch Bar on their too.

Comment: Depends on how you define device. I don't think this is a good question at all, so it shouldn't be answered.

Comment: I would argue that the Macbook Touchbar is just a port to Mac - making it a duplicate device.  As for the car one... wow.  "Can you explain to me why you were driving erratically, honking your horn, and flying down the road?" "I was just trying to beat Knee Deep in the Dead officer..."